# Finding the dual of a Linear program

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

suppose we have

$$ min z = 6 x_1 + 20 x+3 $$

such that

$$ x_2 + 4 x_3 \leq 10 $$
$$ - x_2 +2 x_3 \leq 11 $$
$$ x_i \geq 0 $$

Find the dual.

ATTEMPT:

I wrote

$$ max = 10 y_1 + 11 y_2 $$

st

\begin{align*}
30 y_2 \geq 6 \\
y_1 - y_2 \geq 0 \\
4y_1 + 2 y_2 \geq 20 \\
y_i \geq 0 
\end{align*}

but the lecture notes say $y_i \leq 0$. I dont understand why this is so. probabtly is it a typo?

Comment: Doesn´t $x_1$ appear at the constraints? Your primal looks a bit messy.

Comment: did you appreciate my answer?

Comment: i did! thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lecturer is right. The constraints of your min problem are $\leq$, so the primal is equivalent to:

$$\begin{align} \min \quad & 6 x_1 + 20 x_3 \\
\text {s.t.} \quad & -x_2 - 4 x_3 \geq -10 \\
& -30 x_1 + x_2 -2 x_3 \geq -11 \\
& x_i \geq 0 
\end{align}$$

whose dual is:
$$\begin{align} \max \quad & -10 y_1 -11 y_2 \\
\text {s.t.} \quad & 30 y_2 \leq 6 \\
& -y_1 + y_2 \leq 0 \\
& - 4y_1 -2 y_2 \leq 20 \\
& y_i \geq 0 
\end{align}$$
Now replace $y$ with $-y$ to obtain the solution of the teacher.